# How to replace a range of binary characters

Tags: ruby, regex, binary, range

How do I replace a range of binary characters, similar to having a range of regular characters (`"[a-z]"`) in a regexp?  I'm trying this:

```
2.4.0 :016 > text.gsub([160.chr-194.chr], ' ')
NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for "\xA0":String
Did you mean?  -@
  from (irb):16
  from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
  from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
  from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
  from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

but I am getting the

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for "\xA0":String
```

error that you see above.

I don't have to use a regular expression, but couldn't think of anything else that allowed me to substitute a range of things.

I'm using Ruby 2.4.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please pay attention to your spelling and grammar. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion list, it's an online reference, where those things do matter. We have to fix those if you don't, which takes away the time we could spend helping others.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you wanted to replace characters between ASCII values 97 to 127 with a space:

```
irb(main):002:0> text = 'TeStInG'
=> "TeStInG"
irb(main):003:0> (97..127).each { |e| text.gsub!(e.chr,' ') }
=> 97..127
irb(main):004:0> text
=> "T S I G"
```

Alternately, you can try something like this:

```
irb(main):024:0> text.gsub(/[\x00-\x20]/, 'Z')
=> "TZSZIZG"
```

Comment: Perhaps asking hte painfully obvious, but to get this working with my example, am I using "(160..194).each { |e| text.gsub!(e.chr,' ') }"?

Comment: Yes, but try my 2nd version as well. I believe it is closer to your original intent (and perhaps more efficient); just use the hex values of the range you want.

Comment: When I try the second solution using "td_text.gsub(/[\xA0-\xC2]/, ' ')", it fails with the error "invalid multibyte escape: /[\xA0-\xC2]/".  The first solution also fails, but with the error, "Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT"

Comment: We're starting to get into the weeds here, but...   https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Encoding.html

Comment: You could force the encoding to ASCII-8Bit.

Comment: Ok.  Am I to assume then, that your solution only works if the encoding of the variable in question is "ASCII-8Bit"?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
str.tr("\xA0-\xC2", ' ')
```

Using a hexadecimal `\x` escape sequence.

Or if the charcodes are not static

```
charset = [160.chr,194.chr].join('-')
str.tr(charset, ' ')
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I ran "td_text.tr("\xA0-\xC2", ' ')", I got the error, "ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8".  When I output the problematic string to the screen it takes up several lines, but contains the visible text "  ?PLACE".

Comment: The problem is that `"\xA0-\xC2"` and `[160.chr,194.chr].join('-')` are generating 8-bit ASCII, and Ruby defaults to UTF-8 now. How to tell Ruby to use 8-bit ASCII is covered in the documentation and multiple pages on the internet and SO.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain so I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Meditate on this:

```
160.to_s(16) # => "a0"
194.to_s(16) # => "c2"
```

`"a0"` and `"c2"` are the hexadecimal representations for 160 and 194 respectively. Typically we use the hexadecimal version because decimals can cause confusion.

You can use `"\xa0"` or `"\u00a0"`, depending on whether you're using 8-bit ASCII, or UTF-8 or Unicode. Current Rubies default to UTF-8.

Here's a string consisting of the character range to test against:

```
text = ("\u00a0" .. "\u00c2").to_a.map(&:chr).join
# => " ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂ"
```

This is how to tell Ruby to modify all characters in that range:

```
text.gsub(/[\u00A0-\u00c2]/, ' ')
# => "                                   "
```

All that said, I'd recommend using `tr` as in [akuhn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577499/128421). `tr` is faster for this purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I set a variable to 'text = "\r\n  \xA0PLACE \r\n  "' and then run "text.gsub(/[\u00A0-\u00c2]/, ' ')", I get the error "ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8".

Comment: You probably need to read about telling Ruby to use 8-Bit ASCII or converting from 8-Bit ASCII to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
string = "\xA0"
string.gsub( /[\x00-\xFF]/, '' )
=> " "
```

This covers the range of ASCII characters between 0x00 (0 decimal) and 0xFF (255 decimal).